# Programatically run the javadoc command on entire package gives javadoc: warning - No source files for package

Tags: java, javadoc

I was able to run it against a single Java file with the following code.

```
Main.execute(new String[]{"-doclet", "com.prime.ListTags", "-docletpath"
            , "."
            , "./src/com/prime/system/middlelayer/Calculator.java"});
```

And I have three sub packages inside `system`. I want to run the javadoc against all the source files inside those.
Anyway I tried to run the javaDoc against all the classes inside `middlelayer` package but it will give a warning saying **javadoc: warning - No source files for package middlelayer**

```
Main.execute(new String[]{"-doclet", "com.prime.ListTags", "-docletpath"
            , "."
            , "-sourcepath"
            , "./src/com/prime/system"
            , "-subpackages"
            , "middlelayer"});
```

Which output,

> Loading source files for package middlelayer...
>   Constructing Javadoc information...
>   javadoc: warning - No source files for package middlelayer
>   1 warning

Any idea how to resolve that ?

Comment: You sure `-sourcepath` shouldn't just be `./src`, the root of your Java source file hierarchy, and `-subpackages` should be `com.prime.system.middlelayer`, the full name of the package?

Comment: ohh actually It worked. Thank you for the tip. Btw can you please explain it a little bit. Might be with an answer so I can accept it.